# Error en el análisis, que puede estar ocurriendo?

Tags: r

```
Modelo<- '
Conf=~12+13+14+15+16
Satisf=~17+18+19+20+21+22+23
Lealtad=~24+25+26+27+28+29
Reputacion=~30+31+32+33+34_1+34_2+34_3+34_4+34_5+35_1+35_2+35_3+36
#MR=~12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29
#ME=~7+8+9+10+11
Doc=~10
##Regresiones
Satisf~Conf #H4
Conf~Lealtad  #H5
Lealtad~Satisf #H6
Reputacion~Satisf+Conf+Lealtad #H7
#Detalle H4
#MR~Doc
Reputacion~Doc
 '
data <- (datos1[,c(12:29)])

    data 
    library(psych)
    library(ctv, lavaan)
    library(GPArotation)
    omegaSem(data)
    omega(data)

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con Rstudio, tengo definido este modelo y al
```

aplicar los pasos anteriores me resulta un error:

> ```
> omegaSem(data)
> found:  12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
> expected:  ..constant.. 
> Error in lav_samplestats_from_moments(sample.cov = sample.cov, sample.mean = sample.mean,  : 
>   lavaan ERROR: rownames of covariance matrix do not match the model!
>   found: 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
>   expected: ..constant..
> ```

Aunque me muestra esta información y este gráfico, quisiera saber si estoy haciendo algo mal?

```
omega(data)
Omega 
Call: omegah(m = m, nfactors = nfactors, fm = fm, key = key, flip = flip, 
    digits = digits, title = title, sl = sl, labels = labels, 
    plot = plot, n.obs = n.obs, rotate = rotate, Phi = Phi, option = option, 
    covar = covar)
Alpha:                 0.96 
G.6:                   0.97 
Omega Hierarchical:    0.8 
Omega H asymptotic:    0.83 
Omega Total            0.97 

Schmid Leiman Factor loadings greater than  0.2 
      g   F1*   F2*   F3*   h2   u2   p2
12 0.75              0.59 0.92 0.08 0.61
13 0.75              0.52 0.85 0.15 0.67
14 0.77        0.38       0.73 0.27 0.80
15 0.79        0.43       0.82 0.18 0.77
16 0.76        0.25       0.68 0.32 0.85
17 0.62  0.38             0.56 0.44 0.69
18 0.75  0.38             0.73 0.27 0.76
19 0.81  0.25  0.22       0.78 0.22 0.84
20 0.79        0.30       0.73 0.27 0.84
21 0.65                   0.50 0.50 0.84
22 0.56  0.32  0.21       0.49 0.51 0.64
23 0.73  0.32  0.21       0.67 0.33 0.79
24 0.63  0.60             0.77 0.23 0.52
25 0.65  0.40             0.60 0.40 0.71
26 0.58  0.41             0.54 0.46 0.63
27 0.41  0.22             0.22 0.78 0.75
28 0.76  0.31             0.71 0.29 0.81
29 0.55  0.31             0.43 0.57 0.71

With eigenvalues of:
   g  F1*  F2*  F3* 
8.60 1.55 0.72 0.85 

general/max  5.54   max/min =   2.15
mean percent general =  0.74    with sd =  0.09 and cv of  0.13 
Explained Common Variance of the general factor =  0.73 

The degrees of freedom are 102  and the fit is  1.53 
The number of observations was  231  with Chi Square =  337.84  with prob <  4.9e-27
The root mean square of the residuals is  0.04 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.04
RMSEA index =  0.1  and the 10 % confidence intervals are  0.089 0.112
BIC =  -217.29

Compare this with the adequacy of just a general factor and no group factors
The degrees of freedom for just the general factor are 135  and the fit is  3.81 
The number of observations was  231  with Chi Square =  848.02  with prob <  1e-103
The root mean square of the residuals is  0.11 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.12 

RMSEA index =  0.151  and the 10 % confidence intervals are  0.142 0.161
BIC =  113.29 

Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                 g  F1*   F2*  F3*
Correlation of scores with factors            0.91 0.79  0.62 0.82
Multiple R square of scores with factors      0.83 0.63  0.39 0.68
Minimum correlation of factor score estimates 0.66 0.26 -0.23 0.36

 Total, General and Subset omega for each subset
                                                 g  F1*  F2*  F3*
    Omega total for total scores and subscales    0.97 0.91 0.90 0.88
    Omega general for total scores and subscales  0.80 0.70 0.76 0.65
    Omega group for total scores and subscales    0.10 0.22 0.14 0.24
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola GAMORLOP. Sin un ejemplo de los datos no será posible reproducir el problema y dificultará que obtengas una respuesta. De todos modos algunas preguntas que podrían contribuir al diagnóstico ¿Tienes el mismo problema con los datos de ejemplo de la función o solo con estos? ¿Estás usando las últimas versiones de `psych` y `lavaan`? ¿Probaste reproducir el error desde un entorno vacío? Me llama la atención que el error no sea crítico y obtengas un output después del error. Es output ¿Es aproximadamente el que esperabas? Suerte.

Comment: ¿Falta anexar algo del código? por que veo que defines `Modelo` pero no veo dónde lo estarías usando

Comment: Mil gracias por sus comentarios, voy a evaluar y les estaré contando un poco más.